# if condition is not working in javascript ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax

In alert value is showing as initial but condition of `if(checkoption == 'Initial')` is return always false.........
actual code is this..

```
function changeItem(id,item,option) {

    var xhttp; 
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            if(this.responseText=="Initial"){
            $("#Initial").load("Item-<%=cha_id%>.html #Initial", function()
            {
                document.getElementById("Initial").style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById("Final").style.display = 'none';
            });
        }
        if(this.responseText=="Final"){
            $("#Final").load("Item-<%=cha_id%>.html #Final", function()
            {
                document.getElementById("Initial").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("Final").style.display = 'block';
            }); 
        } 
    }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "<%=landingpage_basepath %>/ChangeItemValue111?info="+id+"&item="+item+"&option="+option, true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the value is `initial` (lowercase) then indeed that if condition is always false, since you are comparing it with `Initial` (which starts with uppercase `I`)

Comment: but i recieve in responseText as value 'Initial'

Comment: i have created sample fiddle with test data, it is printing everything as expected [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kukicvladimir/x18gjp0o/)

Comment: The error may be because of line `xhttp.responseText`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code.

```
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var checkoption=this.responseText;

      alert(checkoption);

   if(checkoption == 'Initial') {  alert(this.responseText);  }
   else if(checkoption=="Final"){  alert(this.responseText);  }
   else {  alert("Hello"); }
 }
};


xhttp.open("GET", "<%=landingpage_basepath %>/ChangeItemValue111?info="+id+"&item="+item+"&option="+option, true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: @vipinkumar if my answer works for you. please vote and accept the answer.